# I want to use yarn like I use NPM, without the lock.file

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, yarnpkg

We've migrate from npm3 to use yarn, because we wanted faster installation times.

In our project we have

1. our main app - my-app
2. module we use as a dependency in our MainApp - my-module.

my-app's package.json:

`dependencies: {
// ...
"my-module" : "~1.4.0"
// ...
}`

Our development metology works like this:
Updating the patch version for non-breaking changes.
Updating the minor version for breaking changes.

That's why we use the tilde (~), so we won't have to update the `package.json` of my-app each change.

Now we've moved to yarn, and we have lock.file.
I understand we need to run `yarn upgrade my-module` each time we want to update it.

My questions are:

1. Can I avoid this process? maybe, not using the lock file? or maybe tell yarn that I'm ok of updating this specific module whenever a new patch is available?
2. When I run `yarn upgrade my-module` it updates my package.json, why??
3. Not only it is updating my package.json, it changes my record to the caret (^) for some unknown reason, why is that?

`dependencies: {
// ...
"my-module" : "^1.4.47"
// ...
}`

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Just don't use `yarn.lock` file, i.e. don't commit it.
2. and 3. Because that's what `yarn upgrade` does.

Comment: Regarding 1, still - developers will have this yarn.lock file in their local environment and the effect will be the same, isn't it?

Comment: No. `yarn` will create `yarn.lock` if it doesn't exist, but only use it if it already exists (i.e. if you have commited it)

Comment: As a side note, `npm` version 5 has similar functionality, but uses `package-lock.json`. There's really no need to use `yarn` now since npm is fast.

Comment: We're using node 6.11.1 and I can't see much of a different between npm3 and npm5.
Installing @angular/cli:
npm5: 56 seconds
yarn: 15.5 seconds

Comment: Fair enough. Seems npm still has some stuff to improve on!